# Java Eclipse, new line after method if include more than one line?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

The code is:

```
public int F1() {
    return 0;
}

public int F2() {
    F3();

    return 1;
}
```

When i apply format, it should be like this:

```
public int F1() { return 0; }

public int F2() {
    F3();

    return 1;
}
```

So

1. if the method include "one line", it should be one line after formatting
2. if the method include "more than one line" it should continue new line after formatting

What should i apply in Java Eclipse Preferences->Formatter?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently impossible, as far as I know. Sorry.